# Selenium 3 на python как установить максимальное время ожидания загрузки страницы

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

в документации по селениуму прочитал что следующая строка после строки с гетом страницы (например driver.get("http://blablabla.ru/")), выполняется только после полной загрузки, а вот как установить время ожидания загрузки там не нашел. использую вместе с gecko вебдрайвером для файрфокса

Comment: Есть хорошая статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/273089/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так.

***Явное ожидание***:

Явное ожидание — это код, которым вы определяете какое-то необходимое условие, которое должно произойти для того, чтобы дальнейший код исполнился.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com/some_url")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "my_dynamic_element"))
    ) # ищем элемент 10 секунд
finally:
    driver.quit() # выполняем если не нашли
```

Этот код будет ждать 10 секунд до того, как отдаст исключение `TimeoutException` или, если найдет элемент за эти 10 секунд, то вернёт его.

***Ожидаемые условия***:

title_is

title_contains

presence_of_element_located

visibility_of_element_located

visibility_of

presence_of_all_elements_located

text_to_be_present_in_element

text_to_be_present_in_element_value

frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it

invisibility_of_element_located

element_to_be_clickable — it is Displayed and Enabled.

staleness_of

element_to_be_selected

element_located_to_be_selected

element_selection_state_to_be

element_located_selection_state_to_be

alert_is_present

Пример:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'some_id')))
```

***Неявное ожидание***:

Неявное ожидание указывает `WebDriver`'у опрашивать `DOM` определенное количество времени, когда пытается найти элемент или элементы, которые недоступны в тот момент. Значение по умолчанию равно `0`. После установки, неявное ожидание устанавливается для жизни экземпляра `WebDriver` объекта.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # ждём 10 секунд, по умолчанию - 0
driver.get("")
my_dynamic_element = driver.find_element_by_id("my_dynamic_element")
```

**Источник доступен по [ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273089/)**

Comment: а счетчик в element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) и driver.implicitly_wait(10) начнет считать с начала загрузки страницы или после полной ее загрузки?

Comment: @JobumJoben я не работаю с `Web` и с `Selenium`, я взял информацию из статьи. Сейчас обновил ответ. Я полагаю, что полная загрузка старницы не ожидается. Но вы можете самостоятельно провести эксперимент, используя модуль `time`